# How not to match string?

Tags: perl

This script will print `aaa`.

How do I get the negative of `$b =~ /disabled/`, so it returns `TRUE`, when `$b` doesn't match "disabled"?

Ie. I want to keep the if-statement, but want `$b !=~ /disabled/`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $a = 1;
my $b = "disabled";


if ($a == 1 && $b =~ /disabled/) {

    print "aaa\n";

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is `!~` I think.

```
if ($a == 1 && $b !~ /disabled/) {

   print "aaa\n";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution.

```
if ($a == 1 && !($b =~ /disabled/)) {
```

Comment: Note that is exactly equivalent to using `!~`; there isn't a special "doesn't match" operation, `!~` compiles into the same operations that `!(... =~ ...)` does.

Comment: @ysth: Perl is usually _interpreted_.

Comment: @ysth: Regardless of what that site says, and of what steps are taken during interpretation, Perl is _widely_ regarded to be an interpreted language.

Comment: Just one that happens to have an internal compilation phase.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, Perl is both compiled and interpreted. The source is compiled into opcodes, which are later executed (interpreted?) by a virtual machine. What @ysth said is unambiguously correct because both snippets compile to the same opcodes, as seen using `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$_ !~ /x/'` and `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'!($_ =~ /x/)'`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
if ($a == 1 && $b !~ /disabled/) {
```

Comment: I had no idea, that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-matching operator `!~`